# Group by returning 0 rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My requirement is to show one record when there are no values in the table. I have achieved with following query:

```
SELECT   TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) DATE1,
           NVL(AVG (column1),0) col1,
           NVL(AVG (column2),0) col2,
           COUNT ( * ) TOTAL
               FROM   table1
   WHERE column3 = 0  AND TRUNC (UTC_TIMESTAMP + TZ_OFFSET / 24) = TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) ;
```

now my problem here is when I add `groupby` clause to above query result is `0` records are returned.

changed query

My requirement is to show one record when there are no values in the table. I have achieved with following query:

```
SELECT   TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) DATE1,
           NVL(AVG (column1),0) col1,
           NVL(AVG (column2),0) col2,
           COUNT ( * ) TOTAL
               FROM   table1
   WHERE column3 = 0  AND TRUNC (UTC_TIMESTAMP + TZ_OFFSET / 24) = TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) 
GROUP BY   TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) ;
```

now I am confused about this behaviour. Why am I getting this strange behaviour?

`25-05-2014       0             0            0`

Comment: `to show one record when there are no values in the table` what does it mean? no values no records

Comment: Thanks fror your response...TAble has no records... table is empty

Comment: in that case what this one record should contain?

Comment: All zeros....updating my question with record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) d,
        col1,
        col2,
        total
from (
   SELECT  NVL(AVG (column1),0) col1,
           NVL(AVG (column2),0) col2,
           COUNT (* ) TOTAL
   FROM   table1
   WHERE column3 = 0  AND TRUNC (UTC_TIMESTAMP + TZ_OFFSET / 24) = TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1))
group by TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1),
            col1,
            col2,
            total
```

Edit---------- added group  by to outer query

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but there is no grouop by clause in your answer... how can I achive group by clause.

Comment: I guess that in your query no `group by` is needed. You always expect to retrieve only one record

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. made some changes to your answer... now I can get `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is a bit arcane, because aggregation queries have an inconsistency when used with and without a `group by` clause.  Your first query is an aggregation query:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) as DATE1, NVL(AVG (column1),0) as col1, NVL(AVG (column2),0) as col2,
       COUNT ( * ) TOTAL
FROM   table1
WHERE column3 = 0  AND TRUNC(UTC_TIMESTAMP + TZ_OFFSET / 24) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ;
```

This query treats *all* the matching rows (even none) as a single group.  It will always return one row, *even when no rows match*.  This is when `COUNT(*)` can return `0`.  By the way, you are allowed to include `TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)` because it is a "constant" (relative to the query).

When you add the `group by`, the semantics change.  So this query:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) as DATE1, NVL(AVG (column1),0) as col1, NVL(AVG (column2),0) as col2,
       COUNT ( * ) TOTAL
FROM table1
WHERE column3 = 0  AND TRUNC(UTC_TIMESTAMP + TZ_OFFSET / 24) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
GROUP BY TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ;
```

This query returns each group represented by the `group by`.  If there are no groups, then no rows are returned.  In this case, all rows are filtered out by the `where` clause, so no rows are returned.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir.. this means group by is applied on returned records from the query but on the query itself... what I mean is query is fired on database but groupby is on the resultant records of the query.. is my understanding correct? plese provide your response.. thank you

Comment: @Siva . . . `group by` is processed (logically) after the `where` clause, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks sir...yes what I understood is group by applied on the resultant output by the query but not on database. Is my understanding correct?